# iOS: How to get the distance of multiple location from one location

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, cllocationmanager, distance

i am working on a project in which i have to show the distance of multiple locations from user's locations. locations are based on latitude and longitude.

i am using the following code to get the distance between two locations is shows nearly same distance

```
CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:28.6379 longitude: 77.2432];
CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:28.6562 longitude:77.2410];

CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
NSLog(@"Distance is %f",distance);
float i  = distance/1000;
NSLog(@"distance between two places is %f KM", i);
```

but now i am struct to get the distance of multiple locations from my location: locaA.

for example i take NSarray for latitude and longitude as

```
 NSArray * latArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"28.6129",@"28.6020",@"28.5244", nil];
 NSArray * longArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"77.2295",@"77.2478",@"77.1855", nil];
```

Please help me to resolve it

Take locaA as user's location

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an array of `latitude` values and another array of `longitude` values? You should instead have a single array of all the `CLLocation` objects you want to find.

Comment: Please Google before asking question.

Comment: @AdamPro13 no there is not any specific reason i thought it provide some simplicity to get the distance easily. and how i use these values into a single array?

Comment: @EktaMakadiya i already search it on google if you know the answer please answer. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CLLocation *currentLocation = ... // This is a reference to your current location as a CLLocation
NSArray *arrayOfOtherCLLocationObjects = ... // This is an array that contains all of the other points you want to calculate the distance to as CLLocations

NSMutableArray *distancesFromCurrentLocation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:arrayOfOtherCLLocationObjects.count]; // We will add all of the calculated distances to this array

for (CLLocation *location in arrayOfOtherCLLocationObjects) // Iterate through each location object
{
  CLLocationDistance distance = [location distanceFromLocation:currentLocation]; // Calculate distance
  [distancesFromCurrentLocation addObject:@(distance)]; // Append distance to array. You need to wrap the distance object as an NSNumber so you can append it to the array.
}

// At this point, you have the distance for each location point in the array distancesFromCurrentLocation
```

Comment: it shows an error: -[__NSCFConstantString distanceFromLocation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Comment: That's because you're trying to call `distanceFromLocation:` on an `NSString`, not on a `CLLocation` object.

Comment: ok and how to create array for lat and long i created like this:  NSArray *arrayOfOtherCLLocationObjects = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: @"28.6562", @"77.2410", nil];

Comment: You need to create the `CLLocation` objects first. You can then use that same line of code to create the array, you just use the `CLLocation` objects instead of the `NSString`s as you showed in the comment above.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below method to find distance

```
#define DEG2RAD(degrees) (degrees * 0.01745327)  

 double currentLatitudeRad = DEG2RAD(currentLatitude);
 double currentLongitudeRad = DEG2RAD(currentLongitude);
 double destinationLatitudeRad = DEG2RAD(destinationLatitude);
 double destinationLongitudeRad = DEG2RAD(destinationLongitude);  

double distance  =  acos(sin(currentLatitudeRad) * sin(destinationLatitudeRad) + cos(currentLatitudeRad) * cos(destinationLatitudeRad) * cos(currentLongitudeRad - destinationLongitudeRad)) * 6880.1295896;
```

Here, currentLatitude and currentLongitude is user's location. destinationLatitude and destinationLongitude is each object from your array "latArray" and "longArray" which you can iterate via for loop. distance is the distance between user's location and locations in array. Obtained distance will be in kilometres.

Comment: thanks for the answer :) can you please update it in detail how can i print all those values

Comment: This is more complex that it needs to be. You can use the `distanceFromLocation:` method on `CLLocation` to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Swift version:

```
let currentLocation: CLLocation = //current location
let otherLocations: [CLLocation] = //the locations you want to know their distance to currentLocation

let distances = otherLocations.map { $0.distanceFromLocation(currentLocation) }
```